# Android: How to get all wifi BSSIDs with GPS disabled

Tags: android, gps

With this sample and gps disabled I am getting no ScanResults. When gps is enabled I am getting results.(tested on Android 7) Is it normal that I have to enable gps? Is there a way to get all wifi's BSSID without gps?

```
public void readWifis(Activity activity) {

    // Get the wifi manager.
    // Provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity.
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    activity.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                                      List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                                      for (ScanResult ap : results) {
                                          Log.d("myTag", "SSID=" + ap.SSID + " MAC=" + ap.BSSID);
                                      }
                                  }
                              },
            // An access point scan has completed, and results are available from the supplicant. Call getScanResults() to obtain the results.
            new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));


    // Request a scan for access points.
    wifiManager.startScan();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not GPS that you have to enable, but the location services which are using either GPS, Wi-Fi or mobile network depending on the requested location.

The problem with BSSIDs und SSIDs is, that they are considered being location information and thus require not only location permission being granted by the user (since Android 8.1) but also location services being enabled.